# How do I include a picture to a question?

Tags: support

I want to upload an image to support my question from my mobile browser.I cannot see any option to do it. How can I do this?

Comment: At the beginning, I had to use Nokia 2700c; there also there was no option of image uploading & switching to desktop version quite bothered me in viewing. So, in order to upload image, I opened an account at [imgur](http://imgur.com); there I posted my pic as it was quite easy (as they supported that outdated device! But the uploading took huge time!:/!) . Then I copied the `URL link` & pasted it like `![enter an image description here][1] <space> [1]: URL link`. That's how I continued to upload my pics till I got my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mobile *site* currently lacks an image upload button, see [this meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153551/263383).

However, the mobile *app* has the button, cf. [this meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191537/263383).

So you need to either use the app, or switch to the desktop version of the site to submit an image.